# Event calling through showInputDialog

Tags: java, swing, events, joptionpane

I'm build one application that needs a request from the user. The first version of the app I made one input window myself, but I found better change to the showInputDialog since it's it's  a pre-molded tool from JOptionFrame. Now I'm having problems with the event trigger; check out the code below:

SearchScreen:

```
public class SearchScreen extends EventSearch{
    ...
    public SearchScreen(){
        userQuery = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type Keywords in english to be requested below:");    
    }
    ...
}
```

EventSearch:

```
public class EventSearch extends TabBuilder{

    public EventSearch() {

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent Ev) {
        try {
            System.out.println("worked");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace(); //print failure
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FAIL");
        }
    };
}
```

TabBuilder:

```
public class TabBuilder implements ActionListener {
    .....
}
```

Then I ask, How am I supposed to call an event through showInputDialog? is it possible? Who is gonna be the listener? Thanks in Advance

Comment: please why isn't there any parent -> `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, ...`, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: @mKorbel my mistake, i forgot to remove the components I was using on the test version code

Comment: i don't know why you are adding event handling here, but for this scenario i think it's of no use.. after the **userQuery** is got from the inputDialog you could just check if the var is null or empty.. then proceed on with some methods.. And I suggest studying the JOptionPane class further to add customization to it

Comment: @Dreamer I realised that just now ;) ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer - its indeed to carry on the code the Event Search class and pull the trigger to one action like this, Instead it's better to do:

```
public SearchScreen(){

        userQuery = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type Keywords in english to be requested below:");

            try {

                 //Your Action with the String  

            } catch (IOException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace(); //print failure
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FAILURE");
            }

    }
```

Comment: Actually the method you are using `showInputDialog(...)` returns a `String`, so there is no need to cast it to `String` again :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw I know this, but I became superise with eclipse that told me to cast it - don't know exactly why oO